# Applying for post doc position when letter of recommendation from PhD advisers not available

Tags: postdocs, recommendation-letter

I did my PhD in Electrical Engineering with supervision from three people. Very hard times during PhD as there was not much supervision from the three. Presently, I am working in an industry doing R and D, but look forward to apply for post doctoral positions. One of my advisers have told me he won't recommend me for any university in the foreign country, the second one is not reachable and the third is very rude fellow. In short, I wont get recommendation from any. What are chances for a post-doctoral position in a reputed university.

I have 3 international journals (2 Elsevier and 1 IEEE) and 3 conferences from my PhD work. I also have a Best Paper Award from one of the main IEEE conferences (EMBC 2014). I can manage reference letters from my masters advisers. Will recommendation from my masters advisers sufficient for applying to post-doctoral studies? Chances of getting a recommendation from any faculty from the university where I did PhD is very low.

Comment: I am in industry, not academia, but it surprises me to consider a postdoc position at any time other than immediately after a PhD.  "Research staff" is another matter.  I also think that if I were looking for a postdoc and a candidate had no recommendation from their advisor, it would be a really hard sell.

Comment: I think it is a very field dependent question, with a strong case by case factor. PD is generally not a glamorous job, so if you have useful skill set, I would expect several professors skipping the part. You may also want to have a better looking excuse than what you have now why those people don't give you a recommendation letter

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the field. Still try the very rude fellow. Perhaps they are at least forthcoming? Also the recommendation letter maybe requested AFTER you have an offer depending on the country, which basically means your Master's supervisors would be game.